# How to scale kind cluster

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kind

I'm having difficulties.
I'm wanting to discover the kind, the type of tool (K8S on prem) for personal purposes and also terraform deployments.

Someone who managed to deploy and scale these clusters?

thanks in advance

Comment: Something like this https://github.com/shahdewang/tinyurl/blob/main/k8s/kind-config.yaml

Comment: ok, interesting. 
i mean do it with terraform, i never discovered nothing similar.

Comment: so does that mean i can only scale my cluster when i'm creating the "master cluster type"?
for instance:
kind create cluster --config kind-config.yaml and this yaml you gave me as config?

Comment: per my understanding and usage experience, you can only scale during the creation of the cluster.

Comment: really helped me. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The solution goes through basically: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/horizontal_pod_autoscaler

It is necessary to define a resource "kubernetes_horizontal_pod_autoscaler", for instance:
[Terraform declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAcFz.png)

Deploy it on Terraform and BOOOM, you have it:
[Work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8hjB.png)